# What is the difference between てください and てくれます?

Tags: grammar

I've come across 2 ways of asking someone to do something for you: てください and てくれます

I'd like to know the difference between them

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is in the politeness levels.

「～～てください」 sounds a little bit politer than 「～～てくれます」 with a ***rising*** intonation at the end.  (「～～てください」 is pronounced with a ***falling*** intonation at the end.)

The latter (along with 「～～てもらえます」 also with a rising intonation at the end) has gained much popularity among the younger generations in the last couple of decades.  Quite frankly, I do not remember hearing either of those as a kid very often and as a natural result, I do not use them myself.

I assure you, however, that both 「くれます」 and 「もらえます」 are now very commonly heard in stores and eateries to make requests.  Mind you, those are used by the customers and not the clerks.  That fact alone should show just how not-so-polite those two expressions are.

Answer (score 0):

てください is a formal way to request someone to do something for you. For example,

> たべてください ("Please eat.")

For てくれます, I think you are referring to てくれませんか.

てくれませんか, according to the Genki textbook (Second Edition), is "roughly equal in the degree of politeness to てください". So you can say,

> いっしょに たべませんか. ("Would you like to go eat with me?")

If you want to sound casual with てくれませんか, you can use てくれない.

Hope this helps.